# Understanding a structure which contains a pointer of its own type

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

```
struct node
{
     int         info;
     struct node *llink;
     struct node *rlink;
};

typedef node *nodep;
```

What does it mean to have a structure's pointer inside that structure itself?
Please explain the above structure in detail.

P.S.
I am NOT talking about the trees logic. I am talking about the C struct and the pointer's behaviour.

### EDIT 1:

`struct node *llink` How does the memory gets allocated to this? This is a type which hasn't yet come into existence?

Comment: nodep is a pointer of one structre. which use in whole porgram as a pointer of this structre(node), like suppose we create like one pointer of any integer same as like this here *nodep is a pointer of node structure

Comment: @user1089679 I am NOT talking about nodep. I was talking about `struct node *llink; struct node *rlink;` they are inside the their their type's struct.

Comment: Go outside and look at a tree. The trunk has a left and right bratch. Chop that off and bung it into the ground. Looks like a tree?!

Comment: @Anisha Kaul Ok, just because "Please explain the above structure in detail." sounded like from a textbook, and if it would be an assignment or such it'd be better labeled "homework" to avoid downvotes...

Comment: @its completly tree structure. u have to understand binary tree or any tree example for this

Comment: This image will help you. 
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC168250.gif

Comment: This looks like an `unary` tree (in contrast to e.g. a [`binary tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)) with bidirectional linking (right and left), i.e. a [`doubly linked list`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). A regular n-tree with bidirectional linking would have a `struct node *parentlink` and a `struct node *childlinks[n]`.

Comment: @AnishaKaul : even i am. That image means that the 2 pointers in your structures are arrows in that image. They tell the tree where to go next. Where will we get a value that is higher/lower than the value/info of the current node.

Comment: @AnishaKaul : read this.. this might help you. It is an awesome tutorial about tree. http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_bst1.aspx

Comment: @AnishaKaul Sorry for maybe confusing you, I just learned from Alex Reynolds answer that in a binary tree the children are named "left" and "right" (foreign languages and naming conventions...), so just ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pointer is just a reference to a location in memory ("address"). In the case of a `node`, a pointer to an instance of a `node` is a reference to the location in memory where that `node` instance is stored.

For your `struct` as defined, if you have an instance of a `node` that resides in one memory location, it can point to two other `node` instances that reside in their own memory locations (`*llink`, `*rlink`).

Using a real-world tree as a metaphor, the `*llink` and `*rlink` are pointers to left and right "branches" of a root node of a tree structure, respectively. Those pointers themselves may branch off into further and deeper left and right "subtrees".

Have a read of this [introduction to binary trees](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html).

[image: binary tree]

Comment: The first two paragraphs made me understand what I wanted to. This is like `struct k { int *m};` this means that the instance of struct k can contain a pointer to a instance of an int? Right? Similarily it can also contain a pointer to an instance of some other struct? After all, even if the types are same the locations will be different, so it is NOT `struct node { struct node *llink; };` a pointer to "itself"? Is it?

Comment: @AnishaKaul "so it is NOT struct node { struct node *llink; }; a pointer to "itself"?" -> Correct. `llink` can hold a pointer to an instance of a `struct node`. This doesn't have to be the same instance, although of course it could. (With nodes a, b and c: a.left > b and a.right > c is normal, but a.right > a would be possible, too.)

Comment: @Martin thanks, that explains it. All this while it seemed to me like a recursive pointer (always pointing to itself), hence asked finally. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin How do the memory allocations work for this type of structs? I mean `struct node *llink` how does the memory gets allocated to this? Since this is a type which hasn't yet come into existence?

Comment: @AnishaKaul What we're looking at is the type declaration, not the variable definition. The first time you use that type to define a variable (e.g. `node *rootNode`), the type is fully declared.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, didn't understand. Isn't this a variable decalration `struct node *llink`

Comment: @Martin Anyway, can you put a little detailed "answer" on that. You'll get some upvotes. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul It should read: What we're looking at is the type definition, not the variable definition. The first time you use that type to define a variable (e.g. `node *rootNode`), the type is fully defined. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4):

*Since there is some contradictory information in the webs regarding 'declaration' vs. 'definition', I'll stick to the definition :-) of these two terms following [this post](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=188)*.

```
struct node
{
```

This is the beginning of the *definition* of the struct "node". It also introduces the type `node`.

```
     int         info;
     struct node *llink;
     struct node *rlink;
```

Here are some field *declarations*. The type must be known and it is known, because it has been introduced already. The actual size of `node` is irrelevant.

```
};
```

Now the *definition* of `node` is complete, and it can be used as a type:

```
typedef node *nodep;
```

When *defining* a variable of type `node`, the memory gets allocated:

```
node n = {42, NULL, NULL};
// or
nodep np = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

---

**With C++**: But what if you want to use two types within each other? Then you introduce type B, define type A and define type B:

```
class B;

class A
{
    class B *pointerToB;
};

class B
{
    class A *pointerToA;
};
```

-> This is supposed to show the idea, not be production code. I'm not sure if you can use it in C with `struct` instead of `class` in the last example. If this is not 100% correct, please comment and I'll correct.

---

<strike>[Here is a great followup to the post from the beginning of my answer.](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=238)</strike> Link not valid anymore

Comment: You said: `The type must be known and it is known, because it has been introduced already.` and I thought a type gets known when the compiler knows how much memory to allocate to it>? and with struct k inside struct k, the compiler doesn't know the size of the first struct k, so..? am I wrong?

Comment: That would be true if it wasn't a pointer. But to declare a pointer, the compiler is only interested in the *type* of the pointer, not the size of the structure it can point to. (After all, the size of a pointer is always 16/32/64 bit, depending on your OS.)

Comment: Yes I had forgotten that. Well, pointers have a size of 4 bytes! Hmm. So, the size is know here. Yeah I get it now. Thanks,

Comment: Also, it means that I can't delacre `struct k obj;` inside struct k?

Comment: @AnishaKaul "that I can't delacre struct k obj; inside struct k?" -> I'm not absolutely sure. It might work this way: `struct k; struct k { struct k obj; };` (First a [*forward declaration*](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=238), then the actual definition of the struct.)

Comment: @AnishaKaul Thinking about it, a `struct k { struct k obj; };` would lead to an infinite memory allocation, so it *should* not be allowed by the compiler. (As the struct gets initialized, all its members get initialized, too, which leads to recursion. -> A reference to the own type must always be a pointer or a [nullable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type).) This also answers your question from the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This page has information on what a tree data structure is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

A tree node holds the data value (the `info` member) and pointers to the left and right subtrees (`llink` and `rlink` pointers). The subtrees are also nodes so the pointers are pointers to `struct node` objects. Having pointers let you walk the tree because all nodes are linked through the presence of the pointers.

Comment: I know about the trees behaviour. Here I was asking about the C struct and the pointers in it. In C terms, not in tree terms.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree can be defined recursively like this:

- Every single node (a node without subtrees) is a binary tree itself.
- If a node has a left subtree, a right one or both, it is a binary tree.

The definition of `struct node` follows this recursive definition of a binary tree.

For example:

[image: Binary tree Example]

The above image represents a binary tree. We can represent this binary tree in C in the following way:

The node with value 2 is a node that has no subtrees and can be represented as a struct like this:

```
struct node* node2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node2->info = 2;
node2->llink = NULL;
node2->rlink = NULL;
```

A `NULL` value for `llink` and `rlink` means that the node has no subtrees. Notice that we can represent the nodes with values 5 (the **bottom left** one, not the top right one), 11 and 4.

The node with value 6 has two subtrees (remember that all nodes are subtrees themselves) and, assuming that the nodes with value 5 and 11 respectively are represented by

```
struct node* node5 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node5->info = 5;
node5->llink = NULL;
node5->rlink = NULL;

struct node* node11 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node11->info = 11;
node11->llink = NULL;
node11->rlink = NULL;
```

we can repsesent our node like this:

```
struct node* node6 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node6->info = 6;
node6->llink = node5; /* Pointer to node with value 5 */
node6->rlink = node11; /* Pointer to node with value 11 */
```

The same goes for all the other nodes of the binary tree.

Notice that we are using pointers for the subtrees. The reason is that the use of NULL allows the tree to have a finite number of elements, otherwise, the binary tree would require infinite amount of memory (a struct that contains itself, which contains itself, which contains itself, which contains itself... requires an infinite amount of memory).

(Image taken from the Wikipedia article for [Binary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Tree) and, specifically, from http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Binary_tree.svg/200px-Binary_tree.svg.png)

Comment: Well, you have explained here the trees, whereas all I wanted was the C struct, pointers, and memory allocations. No tree explanations.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I was trying to explain how each part of the struct corresponds to a specific element of a binary tree.

Comment: Yeah, but I had a different question. :)